# Seaborn line_kws color always transparent

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, alpha

I have drawn a line that I want to call "best fit" using `line_kws` from seaborn.
For a reason that I don't know the line is always transparent, even if I haven't defined the alpha.
When I run the code the figure is created, but an error occurs before: "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater large = s > cutoff".
Does someone know what is wrong with my code?

```
sns.regplot(y=power_consumption_pred_train1,
x=y_train_ns_m1,
line_kws={'lw': 2, 'color': 'red', 'label': 'best fit'}
            ).set(ylabel='predicted KWH Consumption (training set)',
                 xlabel='actual KWH Consumption (traning set)')

sns.lineplot(x=(0,3000), y=(0,3000), color='black', label='identity', legend='full', linestyle='dashed'
           ).lines[1]
plt.xlim(0, 3100)
plt.ylim(0, 3000)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your problem can't be reproduced. Are you sure you are running the latest version of seaborn? For some reason only the confidence interval is shown, but not the regression line itself.  The confidence interval is a band using the same color as the line but with a high transparency.  You could try to suppress the confidence interval via `sns.regplot(...., ci=None)`. To make your code more reproducible, you could create a toy dataset. For example  `y_train_ns_m1 = np.random.normal(0, 3000, 100000); power_consumption_pred_train1 = y_train_ns_m1 + np.random.uniform(-500, 500, len(y_train_ns_m1))`

Comment: I had version 0.11.0 from seaborn and updated it to 0.11.1, but this changes nothing. I can suppress the confidence interval, but the actual line does not appear. With the toy dataset I just have the identity line. The best fit and the confidence interval is missing. I have this problem in jupyter lab and PyCharm. So I think it must be a problem with seaborn?

Comment: Try to leave off the identity line when using the toy data, because that line clearly will be on top. Maybe you changed some global setting somewhere? Are you running the test example after restarting your Python environment?

Comment: I am sorry, because it was part of a much larger code I didn't see the Error message: "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater large = s > cutoff". I think the problem was my numpy version. It was 1.18.0 and now I updated it to 1.19.5. Now it works. Thanks for the help and I am sry for taking your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an out of date NumPy version. It was 1.18.0 and works now with 1.19.5.